# Problema con consulta SQL en Oracle

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jpa

Tengo un sistema el cual realiza la consulta de un producto en una tienda. Es decir, en mi interfaz selecciono `todas` y luego introduzco el código del producto y debería arrojarme todas las tiendas con ese producto disponible. El query lo modifiqué para tal fin y probándolo en Toad funciona bien. Es decir, si introduzco el código y `todas` me trae un producto en todas las tiendas y si coloco el número de la tienda, ejemplo `22`, me trae un solo producto. Pero cuando pasé el query a Java, no me funciona igual. ¿Qué podré estar haciendo mal?

A continuación el query en Toad:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT  * from   (select tmp_barra_primaria.codigoPrincipal,
                 tmp_barra_primaria.descripcionCorta,
                 --vi.active_date,
                 tmp_barra_primaria.descripcionLarga,
                 s.store,
                 im.dept,
                 vi.vat_rate,
                 rfr2.selling_retail,
                 TO_CHAR (rpile.detail_start_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
                 TO_CHAR (rpile.detail_end_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
                 rpile.promo_comp_id,
                 rpile.promo_id,
                 DECODE (uil.uda_value,
                         '0',
                         'Normal',
                         '4',
                         'Pesable',
                         '7',
                         'Procesado')
                    estado,
                 rfr2.simple_promo_retail,
                 NULL,
                 im.standard_uom,
                 MFG_REC_RETAIL
          FROM   item_master im,
                 vat_item vi,
                 store s,
                 uda_item_lov uil,
                 rpm_future_retail rfr2,
                          (SELECT    DECODE (im.item_number_type,
                                            'ITEM', im.item,
                                            im.item_parent)
                                       codigoPrincipal,
                                    im.item_desc descripcionLarga,
                                    im.short_desc descripcionCorta
                             FROM   item_master im
                            WHERE   im.item = :item)                     -- DISTINTO
                          tmp_barra_primaria
                       LEFT OUTER JOIN
                          (item_loc il)
                       ON (tmp_barra_primaria.codigoPrincipal = il.item
                           AND il.loc = DECODE(:2,'todas',il.loc))
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN
                       (rpm_future_retail rfr)
                    ON (tmp_barra_primaria.codigoPrincipal = rfr.item
                        AND rfr.location = DECODE(:2,'todas',rfr.location)
                        AND TO_DATE (SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') <=
                              TO_DATE (rfr.action_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
                        AND (TO_DATE (SYSDATE) - TO_DATE (rfr.action_date)) >=
                              '0')
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                    (rpm_promo_item_loc_expl rpile)
                 ON (tmp_barra_primaria.codigoPrincipal = rpile.item
                     AND rpile.location = DECODE(:2,'todas',rpile.location)
                     AND TO_DATE (SYSDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY') BETWEEN TO_DATE (
                                                                    rpile.detail_start_date,
                                                                    'DD/MM/YYYY'
                                                                 )
                                                             AND  TO_DATE (
                                                                     rpile.detail_end_date,
                                                                     'DD/MM/YYYY'
                                                                  ))
         WHERE       im.item = tmp_barra_primaria.codigoPrincipal
                 AND VI.VAT_TYPE IN ('R', 'B')
                 AND vi.active_date in (select max(active_date)
                                         from vat_item vi1 
                                         where vi.item = vi1.item
                                         and vi.vat_type = vi1.vat_type
                                         and vi1.create_date <= trunc(sysdate)
                                         and vi.vat_region = vi1.vat_region)
                 AND vi.item = im.item
                 AND s.store = DECODE(:2,'todas',s.store,:2)
                 AND s.vat_region = vi.vat_region
                 AND uil.item = im.item
                 AND uil.uda_id = '3'
                 AND rfr2.item = tmp_barra_primaria.codigoPrincipal
                 AND rfr2.location = DECODE(:2,'todas',rfr2.location,:2)
                 AND (TO_DATE (SYSDATE) - TO_DATE (rfr2.action_date)) >= '0'
ORDER BY s.store)
```

Aquí funciona bien.

Ahora el query pasado a Java:

```
String stringQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT * " + "FROM ( "
        + "SELECT tmp_barra_primaria.codigoPrincipal, "
        + "tmp_barra_primaria.descripcionCorta, "
        + "tmp_barra_primaria.descripcionLarga, " + "im.dept, "
        + "vi.vat_rate, " + "rfr2.selling_retail, "
        + "TO_CHAR(rpile.detail_start_date,'yyyymmdd'), " + "TO_CHAR(rpile.detail_end_date,'yyyymmdd'), "
        + "rpile.promo_comp_id, " + "rpile.promo_id, "
        + "DECODE(uil.uda_value, " + "'0', " + "'Normal', " + "'4', "
        + "'Pesable', " + "'7', " + "'Procesado') estado, "
        + "rfr2.simple_promo_retail,null,im.standard_uom,MFG_REC_RETAIL  " + "FROM item_master       im, "
        + "vat_item          vi, " + "store             s, "
        + "uda_item_lov      uil, " + "rpm_future_retail rfr2, " +

        "(SELECT decode(im.item_number_type, " + "'ITEM', "
        + "im.item, " + "im.item_parent) codigoPrincipal, "
        + "im.item_desc descripcionLarga, "
        + "im.short_desc descripcionCorta " + "FROM item_master im "
        + "WHERE im.item = ?1) tmp_barra_primaria " +

        "LEFT OUTER JOIN(item_loc il) "
        + "ON (tmp_barra_primaria.codigoPrincipal = il.item AND "
        + "il.loc = DECODE(?2,'todas',il.loc,?2)) " +
        "LEFT OUTER JOIN(rpm_future_retail rfr) "
        + "ON (tmp_barra_primaria.codigoPrincipal = rfr.item AND "
        + "rfr.location = DECODE(?2,'todas',rfr.location,?2) AND "
        + "TO_DATE(sysdate, 'DD/MM/YYYY') <= "
        + "TO_DATE(rfr.action_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND "
        + "(to_date(sysdate) - to_date(rfr.action_date)) >= 0) "
        + "LEFT OUTER JOIN(rpm_promo_item_loc_expl rpile) "
        + "ON (tmp_barra_primaria.codigoPrincipal = rpile.item AND "
        + "rpile.location = DECODE(?2,'todas',rpile.location,?2) AND "
        + "TO_DATE(sysdate, 'DD/MM/YYYY') between "
        + "TO_DATE(rpile.detail_start_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND "
        + "to_date(rpile.detail_end_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')) " +

        "WHERE im.item = tmp_barra_primaria.codigoPrincipal "
        + "AND VI.VAT_TYPE IN ('R', 'B')"
        + "AND vi.item = im.item " + "AND s.store = DECODE(?2,'todas',s.store,?2) "
        + "AND s.vat_region = vi.vat_region "
        + "AND uil.item = im.item " + "AND uil.uda_id = 3 "
        + "AND rfr2.item = tmp_barra_primaria.codigoPrincipal "
        + "AND rfr2.location = DECODE(?2,'todas',rfr2.location,?2) " +

        "AND (to_date(SYSDATE) - to_date(rfr2.action_date)) >= 0 )";
```

Cabe destacar que recibe dos parámetros:

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery(stringQuery);
query.setParameter(1, codigoBarra);
query.setParameter(2, sucursal);
```

... el código de barra y la sucursal.

Espero puedan orientarme en saber qué estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: recibes algun error cuando ejecutas desde java la query?

Comment: *pero cuando pase el query a java, no me funciona igual* ¿puedes ser mas específico por favor?

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta sencilla es que las 2 consultas son distintas.

El ejemplo más obvio se encuentra en el `WHERE` principal. En la versión "Toad", tienes la condición siguiente:

```
 AND vi.active_date in (select max(active_date)
                         from vat_item vi1 
                         where vi.item = vi1.item
                         and vi.vat_type = vi1.vat_type
                         and vi1.create_date <= trunc(sysdate)
                         and vi.vat_region = vi1.vat_region)
```

Esta condición no la tienes en absoluto en el código Java.

Otro ejemplo un poco menos obvio es que tus usos de `DECODE` son diferentes. Tomando un ejemplo en la versión "Toad":

```
DECODE(:2,'todas',il.loc)
```

y comparando con la versión Java:

```
DECODE(?2,'todas',il.loc,?2)
```

Como puedes ver, le pasas un parámetro adicional en la versión Java.

Estas son tan solo 2 diferencias que encontré a primera vista, puede que hayan otras. Obviamente, no puedes esperar los mismos resultados si tus consultas no son las mismas.

Comment: es que en el java lo puse asi "?2" porque observando ese codigo es la forma en que hace el llamado a esa variable, como cuando usas el +, en realidad no se si en el decode see ejecuta el llamado de esa forma, o hay que colocar el campo de la BD

Comment: @Jdeveloper: No es a eso que me refiero. Lo que digo es que en Toad, le pasas 3 parámetros, y en Java le pasas 4. No es lo mismo. En otras palabras, en la versión Toad, si `:2 <> 'todas'`, el valor que te devolverá va a ser `null`. Pero en el caso de Java, si `?2 <> 'todas'`, el valor será: `?2`. Muy diferente.

Comment: ok amigo entiendo dejame reflejar todos y cada uno de los decode de toad (que es donde funciona) a java, gracias y estare al tanto